# mysql connection throughtout the session

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, connection

I have a problem. Successfully made a `login.php` page that uses function:

```
db_connect();
```

to connect  to MySQL database. Now I'm creating another page that would edit previous entries, but I can't access it with simple

```
db_edit(){...   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $insert_query);  ...}
```

because it says either:

```
"Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli" or " Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given"
```

It looks like the connection breaks when jumping to another page, and it should be reestablished from beginning like:

```
db_connect();   //again?
db_edit();
```

What is the proper way to pass database connection parameters from one session page to another? Should I pass `$conn` or $user and `$pass`? How do I do it?

Comment: Can you post your code instead ?

Comment: Your `$con` is out of scope - you need to include it in your function declaration -> `function db_edit($con){ ... $result = mysqli_query($conn, ...` and then in your function call `$con = db_connect(); db_edit($con);`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Gladly, but I can't. I just don't get what's happening here. Nothing's formatted like I want it to. Is there something like Wiki Sandbox here so that I could exercise?

Answer (score 0):

You must include page of database connection to every page. Here you used `db_connect()` at one page but in second you didn't use it so you can not access `MYSQLI` from second page
Let take simple sample

**database.php**

```
<?php
    // Here place code for database connection for mysqli
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass"); //Localhost

    if (!$con) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
    }
    mysqli_select_db("testdb", $con);

?>
```

**Page1.php**

```
<?php
    include_once("database.php");
    ...   
     $result = mysqli_query($con, $insert_query); 
    ...
?>
```

**Page2.php**

```
<?php
     include_once("database.php");
    ...   
     $result = mysqli_query($con, $insert_query); 
    ...
?>
```

If you have more pages then you use `include_once("database.php");` on each page.
here link can help you [Click Here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Session-Managment-System-in-PHP-and-MySQL)

Comment: Ye ye, I was suspecting that from what I've read, but how do I actually do that? On login.php, I have the form from where I POST $user and $pass to database.php. That part works well.

But, when I'm in edit.php file, how do I reopen database again? Do I store $user and $pass as SESSION variables in login.php and pass it on, or what?

Comment: okk.. you should not define $user and $pass at login.php but store it directly to database.php as i did. are you talking about database username and password.right?

Comment: Ok, I've managed to do it, probably very weird. I have two similar functions. When connecting for the first time logon.php calls db_connect($user_name, $user_pass); and checks if user and pass are true and if so starts a session and opens connection to database. Once the session is started all other pages like edit.php, insert.php, etc, call db_connected() with no parameters, which automatically opens database and returns $conn.

Comment: OK thats it you can also do it using single function.